# How to fix this Dropdown in my Navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, navbar, dropdown

My problem is that if I hover the dropdown it does not go over the size of the menu itself. I know I have this problem because of the fixed navbar, but I still want to keep it anyway. Any solutions?

My HTML NavBar and CSS:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: blue;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block !important;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

body {
    margin:0;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    padding-top: 80px;
    position: center;
}

.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}


.main {
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <a><img src="Bilder/ITK_Logo.png" alt="Anscheinend gibt es ein Problem mit der Anzeige eines Bildes." width="100" height="16.6"></a>
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#products" class="dropbtn">Produkte</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="">Amstweg</a>
            <a href="">Mach mit!</a>
            <a href="">Text</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <a href="#download">Download</a>
    <a href="#about">Über uns</a>
</div>
```

[Picture of the Problem itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYDa6.png)

Comment: can you provide full HTML code? I can't see drop down content when test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: blue;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block !important;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  top:100%;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

body {
    margin:0;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    padding-top: 80px;
    position: center;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
.main {
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}
```

The above code should work for your dropdown. 
Try it works.
This must be what you are looking for. Thank you

Comment: But how can I fix that when I hover a dropdown content the hover color is longer than the content itself. So it ranges out of the dropdown